# How can I get all node attributes and values using Xpath?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<xmlRequest>
    <stats>
        <player_stats aid="254664">
            <stat name="nickname">lethallynx</stat>
            <stat name="acc_games_played">671</stat>
            <stat name="acc_wins">397</stat>
            <stat name="acc_losses">274</stat>
            <stat name="acc_concedes">179</stat>
        </player_stats>
    </stats>
</xmlRequest>
```

I am trying to get the value for the stat `"nickname"`.

I tried using:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//@name");
```

To get all of the nodes with attributes, but I can't seem to access their values.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get the value of the stat "nickname", then you can write this:

```
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//stat[@name='nickname']/text()");
Console.WriteLine(node.Value); // "lethallynx"
```

Explanation:

- The part `//stat` returns a list of all the `<stat>` elements in the document.
- The part `[@name='nickname']` filters this list on the `name` attribute, so in this case you end up with just one element.
- The part `/text()` selects the textnode inside this `<stat>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You command is selecting all attributes of name.  Try this to get all element with the name attribute:

```
doc.SelectNodes("//*[@name]");
```

Comment: This gets me the values, but now I can't find what the attribute was equal to. What I want to do is get the value for the "nickname", and my other fields. Would it be best to just have multiple Xpath queries or iterate through the nodes a single query returns?